# CSS - Best way to do a border like this (with link to a website as example)

Tags: css, border

I need to do a border for my website that looks like [this](http://www.livesets-online.com/phpBB3/) one. The only way I know is to  split the website with 9 div, such :

**1 2 3**

**4 5 6**

**7 8 9**

and create 8 images, respectively:

- top-left (on **1**)
- top central (on **2**)
- top-right (on **3**)
- left (on **4**)
- right (on **6**)
- bottom-left (on **7**)
- bottom-center (on **8**)
- bottom-right (on **9**)

The div **5** is attempt as main. But the whole strategy looks not so well-formed. Any tips? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS3:

```
div {
    -moz-border-radius:12px;
    -webkit-border-radius:12px;
    border-radius:12px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nsDRZ/1

Works i all modern browsers. For IE i recommended t0 use CSS3 Pie: http://css3pie.com/

Comment: I don't know if CSS3 is supported to all browsers... I'd like to use the standard for the moment! Anyway, How can I do that code with CSS3? Im a beginner with that version :)

Comment: See also http://borderradius.com/ -- works in everything but IE, but maybe IE9 is ok.

Comment: And, yeah, do this. (Sorry, out of votes.) Avoid all those nasty rounded corner solutions :)

Comment: That plugins looks nice! :) But I'd like to add a border, with another borded line, as the example show...

Comment: Its absolutly Ok to use CSS3 tody. All major browsers are supported and you can find good solutions to get this in IE to work. We used it in serval big projects and it comes quiet handy.

Comment: But in the old browsers it's a big trouble, isnt it?

Comment: What are old browsers for you? Btw: http://jsfiddle.net/nsDRZ/1/ And here is a comparsion chart: http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css

Comment: Uhm...for example the old version of IE! opera? firefox? i mean the old version... :) In any case Id like to do somethings like the link, with a small black border in the the border, with 2 different colors. Did you see the link? Is it possible on CSS3? thanks for all helps :)

Comment: CSS3 PIE, as linked in my answer, makes Internet Explorer 6-8 capable of rendering several of the most useful CSS3 decoration features.

Comment: If you think its not right for... just take 3 background pictures. 1 Header (incl. corners), 1 Footer (incl. corners) and 1 for your content area repeated on - y  axis. Works on fixed width pages.

Comment: Ok, i'll try! Still not sure if i can do somethings like that link (2 different border with different color). But I try. Thanks man :)

Comment: If you have any further questions feel free to ask... Just play arround with my jsfiddle example. Im sure you get it work :)

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use two divs (one for the outer and one for the inner border) and the css3 `border-radius` with a jquery plugin for IE.

The jquery plugin I would recommend is [Curvy Corners](http://code.google.com/p/jquerycurvycorners/), it does not require you to change anything; just add the `border-radius` in css and only browsers that don't support `border-radius` will use the plugin automatically.

But I use jquery on most of my sites anyway, so that´s not a lot of extra overhead.